# Как правильно использовать CommandBindingCollection в тестах ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется вот такой [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), представляющий собой тест и ViewModel.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestViewModel
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCommand()
    {
        var bindings = new CommandBindingCollection();
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel(bindings);
        model.MyCommand.Execute(null);
        Assert.IsTrue(model.ExecutedFlag);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(CommandBindingCollection cmds)
    {
        MyCommand = new RoutedUICommand();
        cmds.Add(new CommandBinding(MyCommand, testCommandExecute));
    }
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
    public bool ExecutedFlag { get; private set; }

    private void testCommandExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecutedFlag = true;
    }
}
```

Хочу протестировать команду MyCommand, однако, привязанный к ней метод testCommandExecute не вызывается, а тест проваливается. Во View, в качестве CommandBindingCollection используется свойство окна CommandBindings, и нужный метод успешно вызывается.

Однако как мне быть с тестами и проверить логику подобной команды? Подозреваю, основная проблема из-за неверной привязки команды и метода.

Приложение в целом следует шаблону MVVM, и хотелось бы понять, как правильно писать тесты в этом случае.

Comment: В тесте вы вызываете команду, но сама команда ничего не знает о методе `testCommandExecute`, т.к. вы делаете это: `cmds.Add(new CommandBinding(MyCommand, testCommandExecute))`. В сети много примеров на реализацию ICommand, достаточно вбить в поиск RelayCommand или DelegateCommand.

Comment: @Bulson _> сама команда ничего не знает о методе_ Хорошо, а кто знает? Как вызвать из тестов testCommandExecute при условии, что данный метод как-то вызывается из View?

Comment: _> В сети много примеров_ Они меня не устраивают, к сожалению. Собственно говоря, Вопрос про подобную реализацию.

Comment: Я вижу вы пользуетесь MSTest. Тогда можно вызвать `testCommandExecute` из теста напрямую, без вызова через команду. Для этого нужно сделать `testCommandExecute` `internal` в проекте открыть файл `AssemblyInfo.cs` (он находится в Properties) и добавить в него строку: `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("НазваниеТестовогоПроекта")]`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что `CommandBinding` — это средство для привязки команд к UI. Сам по себе объект `CommandBinding` является лишь *декларацией* привязки. Для того, чтобы эта декларация сработала, `CommandBinding` нужно положить в конкретный `UIElement`, или зарегистрировать для целого класса элементов через `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding`.

При этом механизм привязки работает так: при нажатии на комбинацию клавиш [[1]](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Generated/UIElement.cs,2195) или мышь [[2]](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Generated/UIElement.cs,926) вызывается [`CommandManager.TranslateInput`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,346), который находит экземпляр `RoutedCommand` и вызывает с ней `ExecuteCommand` [[3]](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,485), тут находится целевой элемент и у него вызывается `RaiseEvent(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent)`. Это перебрасывает управление [[5]](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Generated/UIElement.cs,5777baebbd060428) назад на [`CommandManager.OnExecuted`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,9596620c1bece8e7). Это в свою очередь вызывает [`CommandBinding.OnExecuted`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandBinding.cs,4a695ce22f63393c), которое и вызывает ваш код.

Для чего это длинное и скучное описание? Для того, чтобы показать: в механизме `CommandBinding` играет ведущую роль UI и CommandManager.

Поэтому тестировать `CommandBindingCollection` в отрыве от UI не имеет смысла.

Comment: То есть получается, такие проблемы возникли из-за нарушения MVVM?

Comment: @mymedia: Ну, я здесь не вижу нарушения MVVM. Просто раутить команды по UI понятно как (UI-элементы организованы в дерево), а раутить по VM непонятно. Поэтому RoutedUICommand работает в основном на уровне UI. Поэтому, наверное, на этом же уровне и надо её тестировать.